# ¿problema al actualizar datos de una tabla java luego de insertar, No operations allowed after connection closed.?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

tengo una clase donde inserto datos en la db luego actualizo la tabla pero me aparce este error No operations allowed after connection closed. aca les dejo la clase conexion y la clase donde inserto.

```
//===============clase conexion==============================
public class Conexion {

    Connection con = null;

    public Conexion() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Registro exitoso");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ropa_trabajo?autoReconnect=true&" +
                            "user=root&password=");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }


    public Connection getCon() {
        return con;
    }

    public void cerrar() throws SQLException {
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    }

}


//===============clase donde inserto==============================
public class trabajador extends Conexion {

    private String rut;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido_m;
    private String apellido_p;
    private int fono;
    private int nro_calle;
    private String calle;
    private String sector;
    private int calzado;
    private int pantalon;
    private int chaqueta;
    private int id_comuna;
    private int id_estado;
    private int id_usuario;
    private int id_cargo;
    private String password;
    private String opcion;

    public trabajador() {
        super();
    }

    public void insertar() throws SQLException {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO trabajador values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement sentencia = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        sentencia.setString(1, getRut());
        sentencia.setInt(2, getId_comuna());
        sentencia.setInt(3, 1);
        sentencia.setString(4, getNombre());
        sentencia.setString(5, getApellido_m());
        sentencia.setString(6, getApellido_p());
        sentencia.setInt(7, getFono());
        sentencia.setString(8, getCalle());
        sentencia.setInt(9, getNro_calle());
        sentencia.setString(10, getSector());
        sentencia.setInt(11, getCalzado());
        sentencia.setInt(12, getPantalon());
        sentencia.setInt(13, getChaqueta());
        sentencia.setInt(14, getId_cargo());
        sentencia.setString(15, getPassword());
        sentencia.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(sentencia);
        //aqui proble usando la variable conexion y el metodo cerrar conexion pero al parecer no cierra la conexion a la base de datos.
        con.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que llamas a `insertar`al fin del método cierras la conexión. Si llamas el método de nuevo, inevitablemente te va salir un error, porque trabajas con una conexión ya cerrado.

Deberías separar la lógica de obtener una conexión y cuando la cierres y la lógica que te crea las consultas. Lo que tienes allá es una conexión desechable.

Es muy recomendable de trabajar con un pool de conexiones. Puedes usar por ejemplo `BasicDataSource` de apache-[commons-dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) para eso.

```
 BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
 ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
 ds.setUsername("jose");
 ds.setPassword("mitremendamentesecretivosecreto");
 ds.setUrl(connectURI);
 ...
 // cuando necesitas una conexión, pides una a la fuente de datos
 Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
 // luego haces lo que necesitas que hacer con la conexión
 // ...
 // finalmente lo devuelves al pool llamando a close()
 // Si, entendiste bien, la conexión que te presta el pool no se cierre con close()
 // se devuelve al pool para ser reusado.
 conn.close();
 // cuando terminaste TODO que quiziste hacer con la BBDD, llamas close() a la fuente de datos
 ds.close();
 // eso cierra todas las conexiones que se habían generado mientras.
```

Comment: es que el metodo lo llamo una sola vez  e inserta pero cuando llamo a otro metodo despues de insertar me sale el error mencionado anteriormente.

Comment: ¿que pasa si no cierro la conexion de la base de datos nunca . se puede hacer eso?

Comment: Se puede, no se debe. te actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: si lo hice y funciono. pero igual creo que no se debe hacer. no se que puede ser

Answer (score 1):

Estimado @jose miguel jara, lo que menciona @Stefan Nolde esta en lo correcto, ahora, en estos momentos tu codigo tiene poco sentido, ya que si implementas el metodo `getCon()` y `cerrar()`, para que utilizas la conexion directamente.

La idea que tratas de hacer con la clase Conexion es encapsular la conexion y que puedan utilizar solo los metodos provistos para esto, entonces deberias hacer unos pequeños cambios como los siguientes:

```
//===============clase conexion==============================
public class Conexion {

    private Connection con = null;

    protected Connection getCon() throws SQLException {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Driver de BD no disponible en classpath");
        }

        if (con == null || con.isClosed()) {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ropa_trabajo?autoReconnect=true&" +
                            "user=root&password=");
            System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
        }

        return con;
    }

    protected void cerrar() {

        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                // aqui solo ignoramos, ya que no nos importa si da error al momento de cerrar la conexion
            }
        }
    }

}


//===============clase donde inserto==============================
public class trabajador extends Conexion {

    private String rut;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido_m;
    private String apellido_p;
    private int fono;
    private int nro_calle;
    private String calle;
    private String sector;
    private int calzado;
    private int pantalon;
    private int chaqueta;
    private int id_comuna;
    private int id_estado;
    private int id_usuario;
    private int id_cargo;
    private String password;
    private String opcion;

    public void insertar() throws SQLException {

        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO trabajador values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement sentencia = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
            sentencia.setString(1, getRut());
            sentencia.setInt(2, getId_comuna());
            sentencia.setInt(3, 1);
            sentencia.setString(4, getNombre());
            sentencia.setString(5, getApellido_m());
            sentencia.setString(6, getApellido_p());
            sentencia.setInt(7, getFono());
            sentencia.setString(8, getCalle());
            sentencia.setInt(9, getNro_calle());
            sentencia.setString(10, getSector());
            sentencia.setInt(11, getCalzado());
            sentencia.setInt(12, getPantalon());
            sentencia.setInt(13, getChaqueta());
            sentencia.setInt(14, getId_cargo());
            sentencia.setString(15, getPassword());
            sentencia.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(sentencia);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Ha ocurrido un error al tratar de ejecutar sentencia", e);
        } finally {
            // siempre se debe cerrar la conexion de o no de error, asi nos aseguramos que nunca queden tomadas las conexiones
            cerrar();
        }
    }

}
```

Ahora, que pasa si no cierro conexiones a la BD?

Pues en una aplicacion empresarial esto haria que la performance de tu contenedor web o de tu servidor de aplicaciones baje, ya que estos manejan pools de conexiones que contiene un numero limitado de conexiones ya establecidas. Respecto a esto ultimo, se manejan una cierta cantidad de conexiones abiertas, ya que el abrir y cerrar conexiones implica en una cantidad de segundos o ms extras que va a demorar tu consulta a la BD mediante JDBC. Un pool de conexiones ayuda drasticamente a bajar el tiempo  consultas.

Cuando tu cierras una conexion en un ambiente con pool de conexiones, en realidad no cierras la conexion directamente, sino que delegas la conexion al pool para liberarla y que otro recurso (otro thread) pueda hacer uso de ella.

No tengo bien claro como influye en una BD que no se cierre una conexion, pero supongo que tambien provocaria problemas de performance y hasta de deadlocks si estas aumentaran infinitamente cada vez que ejecutas una consulta, aunque en una aplicacion standalone como esta no deberia tener problemas, ya que una vez termiando el `main()`, mueren todos los threads de esa instancia en la JVM, matando a su paso las conexiones.